# How to invoke SSL enabled Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I need to invoke SSL enabled Web Api from a WinForm application. How do I configure `HttpClient` for this?

These are the pre-requisites I have already completed:

1. I enabled SSL in Web Api using `RequireHttpsAttribute`.
2. I did the necessary certificate import tasks in IIS to make my Web
   Api work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try yo use HttpClinet class with HttpClientHandler.

```
X509Certificate2 cert;
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);

try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().First(p => p.Thumbprint == "...");
    cert.Dump();
}
finally
{
    if (store != null)
        store.Close();
}   

var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks, where does this `CertificateUtility` resides?

Comment: CertificateUtility is my wrapper, somethinh similar to http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2011/05/12/Making-the-X509Store-more-Friendly.aspx. I've changed code to avoid it.